# WolframAlpha fails to return ComputableData

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

Why does

> WolframAlpha["How much rain in Boston on Dec 25, 2016", {{"Input", 1},
>      "ComputableData"}]

return Missing["NotAvailable"], when

> WolframAlpha["How much rain in Boston on Dec 25, 2016"]

works?

Background:

I am trying to pull out the Computable version of the question "How much rain in Boston on Dec 25, 2016"
The form WolframAlpha[, "ComputableData"] was returned from the dropdown menu on the InputForm pod

Comment: I don't reproduce your result, it could be an intermittent issue.  Do you get the same result now?  Also, I would usually try to get the computable data from the "Result" pod, rather than the "Input" pod

Comment: Evaluating `WolframAlpha["How much rain in Boston on Dec 25, 2016", {{"Result", 
   1}, "ComputableData"}]` returns `"no precipitation"`

Comment: Using the result pod gets me "no precipitation", but what I am looking for is the Entity for 'Precipitaiton, Boston Massachusetts, Sunday, December 25, 2016'.